# how to setup IDA pro linux GDB server

Tags: ida, debugging, gdb

I have Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and I am running Ida pro V6.6 in virtual box in windows 8 ... currently I want to debug some Linux elf's using Ida either via IDA linux remote server or gdbserver but I don't know how to set up such thing (remember Linux is the host and windows is the guest and IDA runs in windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Ensure that networking is enabled on the guest system and that it can communicate via TCP/IP with the host system.
2. Copy `<IDA installation directory>\dbgsrv\linux_serverx64` to your host system and run it.
3. Copy the target ELF binary to the guest system and load it into IDA (disassemble it).
4. In IDA (on the guest system), go to `Debugger → Select debugger...` in the menu bar and choose `Remote Linux debugger`.
5. In IDA (on the guest system), go to `Debugger → Process options...` in the menu bar and specify the hostname or IP of your host system, the debugging port used by `linux_serverx64`, and the debugging password (if you specified one when running `linux_serverx64`).
6. In IDA (on the guest system), select `Debugger → Start process` in the menu bar (or `Attach to process...` if the target is already running on the host system).

Further references:

- https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1463.shtml
- https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/cross-win-linux/win32tolinux.shtml
- https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/remotedbg.pdf